# Can we run Containers in Linux machine from docker Images built on windows machine?

Tags: image, docker, operating-system, containers, cross-platform

We have Jenkins Build machines of Windows OS.
But, we have Linux EC2 instances for running our Apps.
So afraid, If we can use the Docker images built on windows to spin up containers in Linux machines.

**Windows machine:**

```
docker build -t "app-image-built-on-windows" .
```

**Linux machine:**

```
docker run app-image-built-on-windows
```

So is Docker images  cross platform compatible?
Please give the answers considering the usage in PROD for long time.

Answer (score 2):

if your docker image is linux based then yes you can build on windows.

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 introduces a significant architectural change as it is a full Linux kernel built by Microsoft, allowing Linux containers to run natively without emulation.

and if your build was successful, you can run the container on linux machines.

Comment: Thanks Yuyanto, Can you please let me know from which Windows version, these architectural  changes are made tor full Linux kernel support in Windows

Comment: Hi, in your docker installation, you can [switch between windows/linux] (http://sujayopillai.com/2018/05/06/docker-tip.html)container subsystem.